# Collection theming in Symfony 2, different for each level of nested form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, theming

My research into this has discovered various ways of theming Symfony 2 form collections, but so far not one which allows you to distinguish between the form_rows of several nested forms, to have them be displayed differently.

I have a 3-layer nested form, consisting of a top Main, which contains several (DB-backed) Sections in a Collection, each Section containing several (DB-backed) Questions in a Collection.  I want to use DIVs to control the layout of my Sections, but I want to use TABLEs to control the layout of each set of Questions.

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="section1">
        <table>
            <tr>Question 1</tr>
            <tr>Question 2</tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="section2">
        <table>
            <tr>Question 3</tr>
            <tr>Question 4</tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I understand how, for a single entire form, I can change the template fragment used by the form_row function to render the rows, but here I want at least two different types of row.  I don't think you can make your own form_row function which works two ways, using two different template fragments.

How can I render one level of fields completely differently from another?

Comment: Have you tried to use CSS styling? With selectors as `:first` or `:nth-child(2)` you can apply rules to the 2 sections.

Comment: You would likely still use theming. In the sections that render the nested collections you will just need to check how deep the current element is. My guess would be to do a recursive check for parents of the current element and if it has no parent you are on the top level, if it has 1, then you are on the second level, and 2 parents you are on the third and so on and so forth.

Comment: @n.1 Thanks, I agree CSS might be one way to go, but I'd prefer to use Symfony theming if possible (as I would for most other tasks in this area)

Comment: @Chausser That sounds pretty good, I think it would work here.  How would I go about doing that parent check in a twig block, could you give an example?

Comment: Let me do some testing and get back to you on this.

Comment: Hi there, any luck with this?  I've got my finger twitching over a hypothetical "Accept Answer" button, even if the answer is "You can't".  I've actually solved my problem a different way (I didn't even realise how much control you had over the way forms are rendered until recently, doh, thought you had to use theming for everything), but it'd be nice to close this one off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, rather than leave this hanging I'll answer it.

What I was asking may not be technically impossible, maybe via @Chausser's proposed nesting detection technique, but it's at least difficult/unwieldy.

In the end I solved the problem by simply using Symfony's normal [customised Form rendering features](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-each-field-by-hand)
 - adding each field etc into exactly the right place within a detailed Twig template.  I was completely new to Symfony 2 at the time of asking, and didn't even realise this was possible!